# How to highlight a text of string in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a random string given below.

> ungs-   und AnimationsprogrammSport /
>   Unterhaltung: Gegen Ge

I would like to display the **Sport** text as a bold.

> ungs-   und Animationsprogramm
>   **Sport** / Unterhaltung: Gegen G

How should can I display text like this?

Thanx in advanced

Comment: How are you displaying the string on screen?

Comment: I am displaying a string in table cell.

Comment: How can i Highligh of text of textview?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not yet support the display of attributed text.

I suggest using [Three20's style component.](http://three20.info/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `CoreText` and `NSAttributedString` in iOS4.

As a starting point, consider reviewing the WWDC videos on text handling...